# METABOX com dropdown estado/cidade no Front-End usando Plugin Cmb2

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Tenho um pequeno problema com 2 `dropdowns` seletores, até aí está tudo bem, pois estou usando o plugin CMB2 e um código METABOX seletor, e está tudo ok no Back-End do Wordpress, porém, quando trago o meu METABOX para o Front-End ele dá erro na chamada AJax.

Minha suposição é que o código não está reconhecendo minha chamada `Get_colors`... essa seria o meu capturador de valores. Segue abaixo o trecho de código onde encontrei o erro no `debug`.

```
        // ajaxurl is already defined in wp-admin, so no special stuff needed.
    $.post( ajaxurl, {
        action: 'get_colors',
        value: new_val
    }, app.handle_response, 'json' );
};
```

Acho também que via Front-End não da permissão para acessar a página de valores para chamar o `success`. Se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito agradecido.

Comment: Definiu também o `wp_ajax_nopriv`? O ideal é mostrar todo o código relevante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável **ajaxurl** encontra-se normalmente disponível apenas no wp-admin. Uma forma de criar uma variável equivalente no front-end seria via a função **wp_localize_script**.

Veja abaixo um trecho de código retirado do codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

```
// in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
```

Aqui você pode encontrar um exemplo completo de uso no front-end :
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/ajaxurl-not-defined-on-front-end